# Exception caught by widgets library type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this error when i am displaying list view builder. I don't know what i did wrong. I think i did not put any int value to String value. Can you tell how to fix it. I provided my code below and also screenshot of my problems.
in this code i am getting a database referance and base on which data base referencre is provided and then it add data to a list and calling list view builder it display data.

```
import 'package:bidding/global/global_variable.dart';
import 'package:bidding/screen/productDetail/product_detail.dart';
import 'package:bidding/widget/tost_message/tost_message.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final DatabaseReference dbRef;
  final String? categoty;
  const ProductListView(
      {super.key, required this.dbRef, required this.categoty});

  @override
  State<ProductListView> createState() => _ProductListViewState();
}

class _ProductListViewState extends State<ProductListView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.dbRef.once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        Map cust = event.snapshot.value as Map;
        cust[Key] = event.snapshot.key;
        // cust.forEach((key, value) {
        (widget.categoty == "Mobile")
            ? mobileDbList.add(cust)
            : (widget.categoty == "Laptop")
                ? laptopDbList.add(cust)
                : (widget.categoty == "Car")
                    ? carDbList.add(cust)
                    : (widget.categoty == "Bike")
                        ? bikeDbList.add(cust)
                        : emptyList.add(cust);
        // });

        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: mobileDbList.isNotEmpty
          ? Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection:
                    Axis.vertical, // Set scroll direction to horizontal
                itemCount: mobileDbList.length,

                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ProductDetailPage(
                                  (widget.categoty == "Mobile")
                                      ? mobileDbList[index]
                                      : (widget.categoty == "Laptop")
                                          ? laptopDbList[index]
                                          : (widget.categoty == "Car")
                                              ? carDbList[index]
                                              : (widget.categoty == "Bike")
                                                  ? bikeDbList[index]
                                                  : emptyList[index],
                                )),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 200, // Set a fixed width for each item
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 200,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              placeholder: 'assets/logo.png',
                              image: (widget.categoty == "Mobile")
                                  ? mobileDbList[index]['imageurl']
                                  : (widget.categoty == "Laptop")
                                      ? laptopDbList[index]['imageurl']
                                      : (widget.categoty == "Car")
                                          ? carDbList[index]['imageurl']
                                          : (widget.categoty == "Bike")
                                              ? bikeDbList[index]['imageurl']
                                              : emptyList[index]['imageurl'],
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Title: ${(widget.categoty == "Mobile") ? mobileDbList[index]['title'] : (widget.categoty == "Laptop") ? laptopDbList[index]['title'] : (widget.categoty == "Car") ? carDbList[index]['title'] : (widget.categoty == "Bike") ? bikeDbList[index]['title'] : emptyList[index]['title']}",
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Price: ${(widget.categoty == "Mobile") ? mobileDbList[index]['price'] : (widget.categoty == "Laptop") ? laptopDbList[index]['price'] : (widget.categoty == "Car") ? carDbList[index]['price'] : (widget.categoty == "Bike") ? bikeDbList[index]['price'] : emptyList[index]['price']}",
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Location: ${(widget.categoty == "Mobile") ? mobileDbList[index]['location'] : (widget.categoty == "Laptop") ? laptopDbList[index]['location'] : (widget.categoty == "Car") ? carDbList[index]['location'] : (widget.categoty == "Bike") ? bikeDbList[index]['location'] : emptyList[index]['location']}",
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          : const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is the error that is displayed**
[image]

**This is the output of mobile screen**

[image]

**This is the database**

[image]

Comment: on which line you are getting this error?

Comment: when i click on error it take me to mobileDbList[index]['imageurl']

Comment: what is the type of mobileDbList?

Comment: it is list type List mobileDbList = [];

Comment: where it is defined?

Comment: it define in my global variable page

Comment: Do you have a class for mobile nodes? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your list after populating them from local db. After that debug the statements line by line and see whether your list generating any **list of list**. The problem you are having sometimes occurs when there is list inserted inside another list, so when you are finding the value for a perticular perameter it references to the list index instead of the actual value.

you can use debugPrint to print or log to see these cases occurs

if that is the case then just only insert the map in the list and the error should be gone.

Another suggestion for your code is to if the value were to nullable then use null check operators to avoid further issue.

hope it helps